# No network adapter drivers after Windows re-install

Tags: windows, drivers

This is a pretty basic question.

I got a PC (Packard Bell Easynote TK11-BZ-010BE) that had linux on it, so I thought, just delete the partition and its alright. Well, it wasn't.

I went into grub recovery and couldn't do anything, so I re-installed windows again.

Now the problem is that everything works expect my network adapter.  When I go to device manager, I get that there aren't any driver's for it installed.  But without internet, I can't install the so called driver finders.

How should I solve this?

Comment: Can you choose the `have disk` option when installing drivers, and search the install disc?

Comment: Yes, but I don't have any disk that has the driver's on it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You state that you don't have internet access on that machine to use a driver finder.

You don't need to install a driver finder.

If you went to the Packardbell.com support site, you would have seen that they used three different wireless cards in the assembly... not in one laptop, mind you.

So, first, you get yourself a USB flash drive, or a computer that can burn a CD and a blank CD.  That is to say you get **EITHER** the USB flash drive **OR** you set yourself up with the ability to burn a CD.

Then, you download all three of these packages **DIRECTLY FROM PACKARD BELL**.  Yes, that's right.  Packard Bell provides driver support for the hardware they sell.  And here are direct links for the Windows 7 drivers (as that is what is initially provided by Packard Bell).

[Atheros](http://global-download.packardbell.com/GDFiles/Driver/Wireless%20LAN/Wireless%20LAN_Atheros_9.2.0.439_W7x86W7x64_A.zip?acerid=634601180335904424&Step1=Notebook&Step2=EasyNote&Step3=EN%20TK11BZ&OS=721&LC=en&BC=Packard%20Bell&SC=EMEA_27P)

[Broadcom](http://global-download.packardbell.com/GDFiles/Driver/Wireless%20LAN/Wireless%20LAN_Broadcom_5.100.249.2_W7x86W7x64_A.zip?acerid=634310914164367122&Step1=Notebook&Step2=EasyNote&Step3=EN%20TK11BZ&OS=721&LC=en&BC=Packard%20Bell&SC=EMEA_27P)

[Realtek](http://global-download.packardbell.com/GDFiles/Driver/Wireless%20LAN/Wireless%20LAN_Realtek_2019.1.1203.2010_W7x86W7x64_A.zip?acerid=634310914553697672&Step1=Notebook&Step2=EasyNote&Step3=EN%20TK11BZ&OS=721&LC=en&BC=Packard%20Bell&SC=EMEA_27P)

If for whatever reason you cannot download from those links, just start with going to the [Packard Bell website](http://www.packardbell.com), choose your country, hover over the support link, click download center to bring you [here](http://www.packardbell.co.uk/pb/en/GB/content/download), and enter the model (TK11BZ) for your laptop.

Now, once you download all three of those installation packages, you save them all to the USB flash drive, **OR** you burn all three of the installation packages to a CD.  You then take that flash drive or CD and put it in the Easynote.  You then install ALL three.  Do you need to install all three?  Nope.  You only need to install the correct one.  Will installing the wrong one hurt your computer in any way?  Nope.  If you install a wireless driver for a wireless card you don't have, your OS will ignore the driver.

For those who would argue this point, they need only think about how a computer could **possibly** continue to function after installing the drivers needed for a USB wireless Nic, after you have unplugged the wireless Nic.  I mean... OMG!!  There are wireless drivers installed for a wireless card that isn't present... and the computer still functions fine!

Yes, there are things you can do to attempt to identify exactly what wireless card is in your laptop.  You can read the label on the bottom of your laptop, since there should be a notification regarding your country's regulations on allowing wireless interference, and that notification should state the company's name (Realtek, Broadcom, Atheros) in the notifcation.  Or, you could take the cover off the panel on the bottom that is covering the wireless card and actually look at it, and either read the paper notification taped to it, or look at the main chip and see if it is says Broadcom or Realtek or what-have-you.  Or you could follow the steps suggested in the other answer.  Yes, you can take the time to identify exactly which card is there, and then only install the one that applies.  However, it isn't necessary.  If you install each until the wireless card works, then Windows will ignore the others that don't apply.

The point is, you Download the driver installation packages from Packard Bell for your model laptop, and you bring them to the computer without internet access using a portable storage medium.  That solves both issues you mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

You can detect NIC type manually, then download and install its drivers.

In device manager, in NIC properties, on Details tab, select 2nd item from dropbox, and look for characters after `VID_` and `PID_` (used in USB devices) or VEN_ and DEV_ (used in PCI).
This is numeric IDs of vendor and product.

Then google for it (or use http://www.pcidatabase.com/), get to vendor's site, and download corresponding drivers.

If it's Realtek (vendor), and you're asking about wired connection, there are really only one of candidate driver: http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=13&PFid=5&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false (select any mirror from string "Win7 and WinServer 2008 R2 Auto Installation Program (SID:1497589)").

With Atheros and Broadcom, there are more choices.

Link to VEN_168C DEV_002E Atheros driver (taken from hasgarion comment, thanks!): http://www.atheros.cz/atheros-wireless-download.php?chipset=37&system=2

Comment: Thanks, I go to Network controller properties, details and then on the dropbox Hardware id's I only get things like this: PCI\VEN_168C&DEV_002E&SUBSYS_E034105B&REV_01 is this what i'm looking for?

Comment: http://www.atheros.cz/atheros-wireless-download.php?chipset=37&system=2  there is your driver. You can use pcidatabase.com to find devices etc. @LogicDaemon you can use the link in your reply to make it final.

Comment: I clicked on the inf file and pressed install, then I get an install error "The inf file you selected does not support this method of installation" What do I need to do now?

Comment: Wait.  He said... "When I go to device manager, I get that there aren't any driver's for it installed. But without internet, I can't install the so called driver finders." so how does giving him ONLY links solve the issue he presents there?  And more importantly, how does giving him links and **not addressing the other major point** of how it doesn't help him get the drivers onto a computer without internet access warrant getting votes up?

Comment: Well, I have another pc, but I meant such programs that look at all your hardware and then gets the driver's.

Comment: @Arno I know exactly what you meant.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for the help, got it solved, went into Driver manager and then clicked on the coresponding item and installed it like that :)

Answer (score -1):

This is what I did when I had the same problem. I just googled the Network Adapter name which I found out in Device Manager in the system settings in the control panel. Just google "name driver" for example "Realtek bla bla bla drivers" and it will bring u to many different free downloads for your driver. I recommend that you use the driver website which will show up in your google search. Than download that onto a CD or get wireless and install it directly to ur computer/laptop.